# Como leer un json en js

Tags: javascript, json

estoy intentando leer un json pero tengo una dificultad al leer y es que solo me lee la segunda parte de los que estan entre las `{}` la segunda linea del json donde el usuario es andrea pero la primera linea no la lee mi json es el siguiente.

```
[{"usuario":"Pedro","idcomentario":1,"comentarios":"Comentarios 1 de pedro"},{"usuario":"Andrea","idcomentario":5,"comentarios":"Comentario 2 de andrea "}]
```

Ya e leido muchos json asi pero creeria que el problema es porque hay 4 {} pienso nose, el json puede ser mucho mas extenso que ese ya que es una lista de comentarios como de una red social
lo estoy leyendo de la siguiente manera.

```
 var json = JSON.parse(rs);

                        d = document.createElement("p");
                        for (let item of json) {

                            d.innerHTML = "<div class='fas card alert-primary text-gray-700 mb-1 col-auto'> <strong class='text-purple'>" + item.usuario + " : </strong> &nbsp; " + item.comentarios + " <br>" +
                                    "<a href='#' class='text-primary text-center' style='font-size:11px;' onclick='editComent(comentario, idcomentario)' >Editar</a> </div>";
                            document.getElementById("comentarios").appendChild(d);
                        }
```

Comment: Saludos. Prueba creando el elemento `d` dentro del `for`.

Comment: Que pena ya me di cuenta el error me falto d.innerHTML += html me falto el +

Answer (score 0):

Todo está bien, estás leyendo el json de forma correcta, solo tienes un ligero error y es que sobrescribes el elemento es decir el valor 0 es el de Pedro y el 1 el de Andrea, entonces lo que haces es que en el mismo elemento primero imprimes el valor 0 y luego lo sobrescribes con el valor 1, por eso parece que solo leyeras el 1, para solucionarlo solo mete la línea

```
d = document.createElement("p");
```

en el bucle for, así:

```
for (let item of json) {
     d = document.createElement("p"); //metimos esto en el bucle

     d.innerHTML = "<div class='fas card alert-primary text-gray-700 mb-1 col-auto'> 
         <strong class='text-purple'>" + item.usuario + " : </strong> &nbsp; " + 
         item.comentarios + " <br>" + "<a href='#' class='text-primary text- 
         center'style='font-size:11px;' onclick='editComent(comentario, 
         idcomentario)'>Editar</a> </div>";
     document.getElementById("comentarios").appendChild(d);
   }
```